# how to make the circle div left center without moving the other parts?

Tags: html, css

Hey I'm really new to this so please tell me if I'm doing it the stupid way.

I'm trying to make a site look like this

[image: http://imgur.com/8actm48]
But the best I ended up with is this (if I use margin-top, it would just drag the whole body part down)

[image: http://imgur.com/gBgyWPK]

---

this is the body of the HTML

```
<div id="container">        

    <div id="header"><h1>Game Course Weekly</h1></div>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 4 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 5 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 6 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> WEEK 7 </a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="body">
        <div class="circle">
            <p> MON </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-block">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-block">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-block">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-block">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="content-block">
                <p>Nothing to do here</p>
            </div>              
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="copyright"> Copyrights © 2014. All rights reserved </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and this is the css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width : 900px;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', Lucida Sans Console, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#nav {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #01afa1, #106760);
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

    #nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav li {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', Lucida Sans Console, sans-serif;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 18px 30px;

        }

        #nav li a {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #nav li:hover a {
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
            left: 1px;
            border-color: #000 #aaa #aaa #000;
            text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #000000;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -kthtml-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            transition: all 0.25s linear;
        }

#body {
    background: #0c0a0a;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 -20px 0 0;
}
    .circle {
        position: relative;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        margin-left: -35px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #0ec1a1; 
        position: relative;
        line-height: 70px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }

    .content {
        margin: 0;
    }
        .content-block {
            height: 185px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', Lucida Sans Console, sans-serif;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: justify;
            margin: 0 60px 0 60px;
            padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
        }

        .content-block p {
           margin: 0;
           position: absolute;               
           top: 50%;                         
           transform: translate(0, -50%) 
        }
```

---

What can I do to make the circle position like desired without ruining other parts?

Comment: Have you tried to use absolute and relative positions with css? Here is a helpful link to learn how they work! http://keensknowledgeaccumulation.blogspot.com/2013/06/css-positioning-rundown-static-relative.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the circle's position absolute and just control it's position with top/left/bottom/right. Also your script is full of problems and will eventually break. I advice you to rewrite it. I'll provide some notes on the problems if you're interested. But to answer your original question

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width : 900px;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', Lucida Sans Console, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#nav {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #01afa1, #106760);
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

    #nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav li {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', Lucida Sans Console, sans-serif;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 18px 30px;

        }

        #nav li a {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #nav li:hover a {
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
            left: 1px;
            border-color: #000 #aaa #aaa #000;
            text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #000000;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            -kthtml-transition: all 0.25s linear;
            transition: all 0.25s linear;
        }

#body {
    background: #0c0a0a;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 -20px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
    .circle {
        position: relative;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        left:-35px;
        top:70px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background: #0ec1a1; 
        position: absolute;
        z-index:3;
        line-height: 70px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }

    .content {
        margin: 0;
    }
        .content-block {
            height: 185px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', Lucida Sans Console, sans-serif;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: justify;
            margin: 0 60px 0 60px;
            padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
        }

        .content-block p {
           margin: 0;
           position: absolute;               
           top: 50%;                         
           transform: translate(0, -50%) 
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yah thanks a lot, I was trying to use several methods so it ended up messy like that. Will fix it once I get the grasp of this relative / absolute thing

Comment: No problem. Did my answer was of any help?

Comment: yeah after I saw your solution I worked around it a bit and it worked :D Btw can you point out some big problems I had up there?

Comment: Surething give me a second to reread the code and write a list. In the mean time feel free to upvote my answer and choose it :)

Comment: I have less than 15 upvote, otherwise I would have done so already :(

Comment: No problem!  There is already a HTML element called <header> </header>
naming a div body is bad practice 
the <div class="circle"> Should be inside the <div class="content"> element,    
use border-bottom in the content-block instead of reusing <hr>

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative and/or absolute positioning. See here to get to know how this works: [W3schools-CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). Further I suggest you change your code, so you're circle div will be within the content div. I suggest you use relative positioning, since relative positioning is in contrast to absolute positioning not dependent on other page elements. Relative positioning is dependent on it's actual position on the page and moved from there by the parameters. So look at your html in a browser and change the parameters to move your circle with relative positioning.

CSS:

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
}
```

This bit of CSS above, for example, will move your circle div to the left by 30px. The amount of pixels you add are always added on the side you give, therefor negative on left to shift left.
You may also use: right, top and bottom.